# Wordpress error unexpected T_VARIABLE in line 1 of functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing this error ever since i wrote a function in `functions.php` . I even removed it and uploaded my backup file on to the server from the FTP.

It still shows the same error. People on WordPress forum do not know what exactly needs to be done.

Please help as it is on my clients live website.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/90/10424790/html/waytofabulous/wp-content/themes/custom/functions.php on line 1
```

First 10 lines of code :

```
  <?php

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 604;

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.6-alpha', '<' ) )
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
?>
```

Comment: What does that line contain?

Comment: Atleast post the sample code

Comment: There is no bug in my code as i can see it on my php editor..how do i paste the whole code?

Comment: You need to post the line of code not the Error text

Comment: I think you miss ; after php statement

Comment: please post code in the Question body not in a comment

Comment: Can you show just line 1 and edit it into the question body?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove spaces before `<?php` tag

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 604;

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.6-alpha', '<' ) )
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
?>
```